# How to make an HTML element hidden and viewable only for certain role only in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Newbie wordpress/php student. I want to make a certain element viewable only for a certain user-role in wordpress and hidden for all normal subscribers/non-subscribers.

Its for a property page on a real estate website. I want to make a specific tab element hidden so only for certain users(agent user role) to be able to see.(The element will contain information such as property owners phone number. I will take the 'floorplan' tab on the property page and change it to 'owner info' tab.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer precisely without seeing the PHP template code for these tabs, but in general, this is as simple as putting that tab's HTML inside a PHP conditional.

```php
// your code that checks if this home is owned by the current user
// var $owner_viewing_property = is_owner_viewing();

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab">Features</li>

  <? if ($owner_viewing_property) { ?>
    <li class="tab">Owner Info</li>
  <? } else { ?>
    <li class="tab">Floor Plans</li>
  <? } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok I figured it out. was super simple lol. But how do I add more than 1 ID check? I want to that field to be visible for admin account and agent account/ 

https://codeshare.io/2Wn1Ml

Comment: For more complicated conditionals involving a multiple conditions, it helps readability to run your condition-checking logic first, assign the results to a single variable, then refer to that single result variable in your template. I've updated your example: https://codeshare.io/2Wn1Ml